# glxinfo vs. glewinfo interpretation

Tags: opengl, glsl, sdl

I have difficulties interpreting glxinfo and glewinfo.

glxinfo gives me this:

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 9.2.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

whereas glewinfo goes up to version 4.0:

```
GL_VERSION_4_0:                                                OK 
---------------
  glBlendEquationSeparatei:                                    OK
  glBlendEquationi:                                            OK
  glBlendFuncSeparatei:                                        OK
  glBlendFunci:                                                OK
  glMinSampleShading:                                          OK
```

I know that I cannot use GLSL newer than 1.30, but I'm wondering, is that a driver issue?

My GPU is

```
 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

I'm using Arch Linux and SDL, and have Mesa 9.2 and Mesa-libgl 9.2.2 installed.

Comment: What OS are you using ? `glewinfo` gives information on the hardware capabilities. To use then you have to set the opengl context in the right way to be able to use them properly and this should be possible if `glewinfo` returns gl 4.0 extensions are supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `glewinfo` reports certain functions being there, that just means it could retrieve a function pointer for them. However the function pointer being available does not tell, that the corresponding extension/version support being actually available. Since OpenGL follows a client server model, the client side interface may very well expose also newer functionality, while the server side doesn't support it.

The list of supported extensions and the reported version are the authorative information on that and you must rely on only those.